# mount command over existing drive, then deleted

Tags: ubuntu, mount, rm

So I had a directory sitting on

```
/dev/sdb1
```

I umounted the drive, moved the backup to sdc1 and restarted the server, still can't see the files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I am afraid so as the mounted data content mounted to the place you previous mounted.  At the very least dual mounting an active disk in two places could cause some definite data corruption.

Summary, the answer is that your rm succeeded in removing files on /dev/sdb1.  Your only recourse at this point is to restore the content from backups.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case, just the backups are a process of manual copying and files over and there are discrepancies. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure the kernel notices when you try to mount the same device twice and treats it like `mount --bind`, so it shouldn't cause data corruption. Of course, deleting a file off one mount definitely deletes it off the other.